# Save As error 'X' object has no attribute 'Y' in QGIS plugin

Tags: python, qgis

I try to make plugin to open, read and then save save in different format, i open .xml file and try to save as / write it in text or pdf format, but i get error message like this :

```
File "C:\Users\Mr.Pakde/.qgis2/python/plugins\latih\latihdialog.py", line 71, in saveAs
    self._save( _filename )
  File "C:\Users\Mr.Pakde/.qgis2/python/plugins\latih\latihdialog.py", line 59, in _save
    f.write( "%s" % self.nmfile.text() )
AttributeError: 'latihDialog' object has no attribute 'nmfile'
```

This is my code

```
cariButton = self.ui.btnCari
        QtCore.QObject.connect(cariButton, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'),self.cari)
        saveButton = self.ui.btnSave
        QtCore.QObject.connect(saveButton, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'),self.saveAs)

    def cari(self, event=None):

        #open dialog
        filename = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open File', '*.xml')

        self.ui.lineFile.setText(filename)

        #panggil isi data
        self.isiDataFile(filename)

    def isiDataFile(self, nmfile):
        #buka dengan open mode baca
        teksFile = open(nmfile, 'r').read()

        self.ui.textFile.setText(teksFile)


    def _save(self, simpan):        
        f = open( simpan, "w" )
        f.write( "%s" % self.nmfile.text() )
        f.close()
    def savefile(self):
        if self.simpan:
              self._save( "%s" % self.simpan )
        else:
              self.saveAs()

    def saveAs(self):
            tulis = QtGui.QFileDialog(self).getSaveFileName()
            if tulis !="":
                _filename = "%s" % tulis
                self._save( _filename )
                self.setFilename( _filename )
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use the variable `nmfile` as a instance variable by addressing it in the way `self.nmfile`. However, this variable/attribute has never been initialized (compare: AttributeError: 'latihDialog' object has no attribute 'nmfile').

You use the variable in a local context in isiDataFile, but as soon as this method ends, the local variable is lost and cannot be accessed any more.

You have to design the flow of your code, that it either will

- Assign this instance variable, before the `_save`-method is called  ( e.g. `self.nmfile = '/tmp/myfile'` )
- Pass an argument `nmfile` to the `_save`-method, so it will be available there